# How to build and execute a procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am having an issue while executing a procedure. When I am executing my procedure, it is not returning any answer. I know that there is some fault in my procedure, but I am not able to figure it out, so please help me in creating a new procedure.

Before showing my code, let me tell you why did I create the procedure:

I am actually working on my project 'Supermarket Billing management system' in that, I have already created a few tables among them, one is the Products table in which, I have created the FINAL_TOTAL column as the procedure, Now I want the procedure to calculate the total price of all the products price purchased by one single person. For instance, when you go to a Supermarket or any shopping center then, after buying few items they give a bill, and at the below of the bill, there's is a final amount which you have to pay.

So, for this reason, I have created the procedure. If you know the problem with my code then, please let me know!!

**CODE:**

Procedure

```
create procedure FINAL_TOTAL(C IN NUMBER, T OUT NUMBER)
        IS
        BEGIN
        UPDATE Products
        SET FinalTotal = FinalTotal + Total
        WHERE ProdCustId = C;
        Commit;
        SELECT FinalTotal into T FROM Products WHERE ProdCustId = C;
        END;
        /
```

Products table:

```
create table Products
    ( ProdId number primary key,
      ProdNum number not null unique,
      ProdName varchar2(15),
      ProdPrice int,
      ProdQuantity int,
      Total int,
      FinalTotal int,
      ProdCustId int references Customers,
      ProdOrdId int references Orders,
      ProdStoreId int references Stores
    );
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PROD_TOTAL
    AFTER INSERT ON Products
    BEGIN
    UPDATE Products
    SET Total = ProdPrice * ProdQuantity;
    END;
    /
```

insert statement in Products table:

```
insert into Products(ProdID,ProdNum,ProdName,ProdPrice,ProdQuantity,ProdCustId,ProdOrdId,ProdStoreId)
values(1,1001,'Syrup',30,2,1,1,1);
```

Execution code of procedure:

```
variable K number;
SQL> EXECUTE FINAL_TOTAL(1,:K);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Output:

```
select * from Products;

    PRODID    PRODNUM PRODNAME         PRODPRICE PRODQUANTITY      TOTAL
---------- ---------- --------------- ---------- ------------ ----------
FINALTOTAL PRODCUSTID  PRODORDID PRODSTOREID
---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
         1       1001 Syrup                   30            2         60
                    1          1           1


SQL> print :K

         K
----------
```

So, this is my code, I don't know what's the problem with my code since I am a beginner, I don't have that much idea on the procedure, and I have to use the procedure in my project because it's mandatory, so please help me in solving this issue!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FinalTotal` is NULL. Use `NVL` or `COALESCE`:

```
... SET FinalTotal = NVL(FinalTotal,0) + Total
```

NULL plus a number is NULL.

```
SELECT NULL + 1 FROM DUAL; -- NULL
SELECT NVL(NULL, 0) + 1 FROM DUAL; -- 1
```

Comment: It was working until I didn't add more than one row, but as soon as I added 3 rows, it is giving me this error:    ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.FINAL_TOTAL", line 8
ORA-06512: at line 1

Comment: @Sushmitashukla Your query in the procedure returns more than one row. For example, you can sum them up.

`SELECT SUM(FinalTotal) into T FROM Products WHERE ProdCustId = C;`

Comment: This is my procedure code:  `create procedure FINAL_TOTAL(C IN NUMBER, T OUT NUMBER) IS BEGIN UPDATE Products SET FinalTotal = NVL(FinalTotal,0) + Total WHERE ProdCustId = C; Commit; SELECT SUM(FinalTotal) into T FROM Products WHERE ProdCustId = C; END; /
  
Procedure created.`

Comment: when I executed this code, it worked, but I am not getting the right output. For example, I entered the price=30, quantity=4 then I got total =price*quantity i.e 120(30*4), till here it worked fine, but I am getting my FinalTotal which is procedure column as 240 i.e (total+total), and in every single row I am getting the same kind of output that is, in FinalTotal I am getting the value total+total of that column, so I don't know what logic I can use to correct my issue. If you know then please let me know!